# DevOps - Maven: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

I'm configuring my maven project on DevOps, but I receive an assembling WAR error.

I've uploaded my project on the DevOps Repository and created a pipeline.
My pipeline is composed by the following job:

- Download secure file
- Maven pom.xml

  - Maven POM file: eq/pom.xml
  - Goal(s): clean package install
  - Options: -X -s $(Agent.TempDirectory)/settings_cqm.xml
  - Advanced - JDK version/architecture: JDK 7/x64
- Copy ear
- Copy shared-lib
- Publish Artifact

Here is my eq/pom.xml file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-be-internal-services-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>cq-be-internal-services-war</name>
    <description>Web Services Batch Module</description>

    <properties>
        <jaxws.version>2.1.3</jaxws.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>was_public</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.XXX</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-be-internal-services-business</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>CQImport</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>cqm-be-services</warName>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                                <targetPath>WEB-INF\classes\</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is the error

```
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9662437Z [INFO] Reactor Summary for cq root 4.0:
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9662755Z [INFO] 
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9664783Z [INFO] CQ root ........................................... SUCCESS [  1.766 s]
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9679554Z [INFO] cq-be-internal-services-business .................. SUCCESS [  4.994 s]
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9682033Z [INFO] cq-be-internal-services-war ....................... FAILURE [  2.156 s]
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9682663Z [INFO] cq-be-services-ear ................................ SKIPPED
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9692819Z [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9697818Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9698294Z [INFO] Total time:  27.116 s
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9699005Z [INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-21T19:21:29Z
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9699671Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9771508Z [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) on project cq-be-internal-services-war: Error assembling WAR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/CQImport/WEB-INF/classes/it/XXXX/cq/ws/StorCServiceImpl.java -> [Help 1]
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9779002Z org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) on project cq-be-internal-services-war: Error assembling WAR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/CQImport/WEB-INF/classes/it/XXXX/cq/ws/StorCServiceImpl.java
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9782836Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9785031Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9785666Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9788094Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9790406Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9793248Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9796342Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9797083Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9799040Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9801111Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9801637Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9803826Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9804325Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9806290Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9806802Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9808767Z     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9809491Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9813743Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9817220Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9817876Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9820814Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9823721Z Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error assembling WAR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/CQImport/WEB-INF/classes/it/XXXX/cq/ws/StorCServiceImpl.java
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9826073Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute (WarMojo.java:191)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9828017Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9828653Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9830680Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9832604Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9834580Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9836633Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9838785Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9839468Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9842258Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9842760Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9847705Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9848003Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9848275Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9852637Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9852929Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9853223Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9857093Z     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9857426Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9861871Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9862264Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9862640Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9869585Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9871441Z Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/CQImport/WEB-INF/classes/it/XXXX/cq/ws/StorCServiceImpl.java
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9877442Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext (AbstractArchiver.java:497)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9878235Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain (AbstractZipArchiver.java:233)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9883131Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute (AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9883577Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:944)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9884135Z     at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive (MavenArchiver.java:598)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9888892Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging (WarMojo.java:244)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9889647Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute (WarMojo.java:175)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9890223Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9900525Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9901423Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9901787Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9905448Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9905917Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9906389Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9912639Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9913575Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9914083Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9919441Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9925021Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9925448Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9932561Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9932888Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9933263Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9939770Z     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9940328Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9940670Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9946696Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9947547Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9947990Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9954875Z Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/CQImport/WEB-INF/classes/it/XXXX/cq/ws/StorCServiceImpl.java
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9955448Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException (UnixException.java:86)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9959953Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:102)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9960340Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException (UnixException.java:107)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9961065Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.readAttributes (UnixFileAttributeViews.java:210)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9967194Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Posix.readAttributes (UnixFileAttributeViews.java:123)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9967739Z     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes (UnixFileSystemProvider.java:144)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9968210Z     at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.readAttributes (LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:97)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9974220Z     at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes (Files.java:1686)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9974654Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.attributes.Java7AttributeUtils.getFileAttributes (Java7AttributeUtils.java:124)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9975118Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.attributes.Java7FileAttributes.<init> (Java7FileAttributes.java:62)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9979544Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.addResourcesJava7 (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:188)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9980267Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.getResources (PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.java:236)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9984970Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext (AbstractArchiver.java:493)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9985428Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain (AbstractZipArchiver.java:233)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9985854Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute (AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9990046Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive (AbstractArchiver.java:944)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9990462Z     at org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.createArchive (MavenArchiver.java:598)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9990830Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging (WarMojo.java:244)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9994593Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute (WarMojo.java:175)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9994989Z     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9998529Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9998951Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
2020-10-21T19:21:29.9999322Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0003166Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0003655Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0007609Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0008113Z     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0012565Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0013088Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0017645Z     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0018189Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0018878Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0022611Z     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0022914Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0023258Z     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0026795Z     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0027149Z     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:607)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0030670Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0031197Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0031564Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0035015Z     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0035262Z [ERROR] 
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0035392Z [ERROR] 
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0035658Z [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0039778Z [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0040037Z [ERROR] 
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0040233Z [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0040783Z [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :cq-be-internal-services-war
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0163780Z The process '/usr/share/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn' failed with exit code 1
2020-10-21T19:21:30.0166531Z Could not retrieve code analysis results - Maven run failed.
2020-10-21T19:21:30.9966657Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2020-10-21T19:21:31.0097059Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2020-10-21T19:21:31.0432050Z No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-business/target/surefire-reports/TEST-it.xxx.cq.ws.jaxrs.TestGNService.xml'.
2020-10-21T19:21:31.0438408Z No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/1/s/eq/cq-be-internal-services-war/target/surefire-reports/TEST-it.xxx.cq.TestImportMassivo.xml'.
2020-10-21T19:21:31.0553009Z ##[error]Build failed.
2020-10-21T19:21:31.0603213Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
2020-10-21T19:21:31.1493783Z ##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
2020-10-21T19:21:31.1495079Z ##[section]Finishing: Maven eq/pom.xml
```

I've already tried different configuration. Here some of them:

- To change the JDK version in DevOps setting it with the Default value.
- To eliminate the `source` and the `target` tag in the pom file and setting the JDK version in DevOps with `JDK 7` value
- To add `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` line in the pom file

I'm stuck with this error and I don't have any other idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

I have changed the tag `<targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>` to  `<targetPath>WEB-INF\classes\</targetPath>`.

Comment: The problem was due to the OS installed on the server.
For Linux: <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>